# withAuth HOC renders private page for a few seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, next.js

I have a problem regarding my withAuth HOC in my Next JS project. This should let users access some routes only if they are logged in.

The problem is that it needs like 1 or 2 seconds to process the request and in this time the private route is rendered, then it is replaced with the desired one (the one for sign in).

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { LaLoader } from "../components/LaLoader";
import { useMeQuery } from "../generated/graphql";

export const withAuth = (Component) => {
    const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
        const router = useRouter();
        const { data, loading } = useMeQuery()

        useEffect(() => {
            const getUser = async () => {
                if (!data?.me) {
                    router.push('/signin');
                }
                if (!data?.me.isCompleted) {
                    router.push('/complete-profile')
                }
            };
            getUser();
        });
        if (loading) {
            return <LaLoader />
        }
        return data?.me ? <Component data={data} /> : null;
    };

    return AuthenticatedComponent;
};
```

The behaviour I want is: if the request is still processing (loading), on the page will be rendered a loader; if the user isn't logged in he will be redirected to the sign in page and if he's signed in the private component will be displayed.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this code snippet the code you've an issue with (*the code that displayed the protected component*)? Or is this the code you want the desired behavior with? The code appears to be what you describe wanting. Is the issue that `loading` is falsey on the initial render cycle before the `useEffect` hook can call `getuser`?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your reply. This is the code with the issue. Loading is true on the initial render cycle. I've tested this code. The problem is that I signed in with an account with isCompleted set to false. This should redirect me to /complete-profile when I try to access the protected route. The actual behaviour is that after I log in, the protected route is displayed for like 1-2 seconds and then I am redirected to the /complete-profile route. I want to be redirected instantly. I hope that you'll be able to fully understand the situation.

Comment: Well, unless you can make the `getUser` function instant you'll need some more "loading" state to wait for that promise to resolve *then* issue any redirects.

Comment: How I can do this?

Comment: Does `getUser` need to be declared `async`? It doesn't appear call any asynchronous code nor `await` anything.

Comment: You're right. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `getUser` function needs to be declared `async` since it doesn't appear to call any asynchronous code nor `await` anything. With the synchronous code I think you just need to wait for the `loading` state to clear and do the same check to redirect the user.

Example:

```
export const withAuth = (Component) => (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data, loading } = useMeQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      if (!data?.me) {
        router.push("/signin");
      } else if (!data?.me?.isCompleted) {
        router.push("/complete-profile");
      }
    }
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <LaLoader />;
  }
  return data?.me ? <Component {...props} data={data} /> : null;
};
```

[image: Edit withauth-hoc-renders-private-page-for-a-few-seconds]